# why doesn't this 'addRow' javascript work in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have the following javascript that adds a new row to the bottom of a table.

It works fine in Firefox, but it doesn't work in IE (version 8).

There are no visible errors, as far as I can tell.

Any ideas are very helpful!

```
function addRow() {

  // locate the last row in the table
  var table = document.getElementById("approversTable");

  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var rowToClone;
  for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].id != "") {
      rowToClone = rows[i];
    }
  }

  // clone the row
  var clone = rowToClone.cloneNode(true);
  var rowId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
  clone.id = rowId;
  // add the new row to the table
  table.appendChild(clone);

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: did you tried to add the tr to tbody instead of the table node?

Comment: Check the DOM/HTML after, maybe it did add it, but just doesn't look the way you expect.  Maybe related to the fact that IE adds tbody tags for you.

Comment: Thanks @Edorka that was it!  Adding to the tbody instead of the table works now.  If you'd like to post and answer, I'm happy to mark it as correct!

Comment: @RobertHume I added an example tell me if you would find useful to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the table tbody element instead of the table directly.

```
   function addRow() {
     var table = document.getElementById("approversTable");
     var tbody = table.tbodies[0];
     var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      var rowToClone;
      for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        if (rows[i].id != "") {
          rowToClone = rows[i];
        }
      }

      // clone the row
      var clone = rowToClone.cloneNode(true);
      var rowId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
      clone.id = rowId;
      // add the new row to the table
      tbody.appendChild(clone);
   }
```

more info at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_tbodies.asp